# Gráfico de curvas conjuntas em ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, plot

Estou tentando realizar um gráfico que contém a evolução da variável `Var1` em função da variável `Var2` conjuntamente ao invés de separado como está sendo apresentado na figura abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para realizar o gráfico acima eu utilizei a seguinte rotina computacional:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)

p1=ggplot(subset(datanew2, Var3 < 5), aes(Var2,Var1)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p2=ggplot(subset(datanew2, Var3 < 11), aes(Var2,Var1)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p3=ggplot(subset(datanew2, Var3 < 16), aes(Var2,Var1)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p4=ggplot(subset(datanew2, Var3 < 20), aes(Var2,Var1)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

No entanto, o que eu gostaria de realizar está próximo do que está sendo apresentado a seguir (na rotina computacional abaixo), porém, perceba que algo de errado está acontecendo, uma vez que o resultado apresentado no gráfico não condiz com a imagem acima onde se encontra as curvas separadas. Para tentar realizar o que eu gostaria, criei uma variável que contém as diferentes classificações obtidas por meio da variável `Var3` e então utilizei a função `group` contendo a variável criada dentro da função `aes` ambas internas a função `ggplot`, mas o resultado não é satisfatório como já foi descrito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)

datanew2 <- datanew2%>%dplyr::mutate(Factor = ifelse(Var3 < 5,
                                              "A",ifelse(Var3 < 11, "B", ifelse(Var3 < 16, "C",
                                                                                 ifelse(Var3 < 20, "D")))))
ggplot(datanew2, aes(group=Factor,Var2,Var1)) +
  geom_smooth()  +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: O gráfico parece diferente porque os eixos têm escalas diferentes.

Comment: Só um detalhe (relativo à edição feita na resposta): se os dados eram sigilosos, eles nem deveriam ter sido colocados aqui (pois [ainda é possível vê-los no histórico de edições](/posts/501231/revisions)). O ideal, nesses casos, é criar dados "falsos" ou mascarados, de forma a não revelar as partes sigilosas, **mas que ainda sim reproduzam o mesmo problema** (é o tal do [mcve] que a gente tanto fala...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há nada de errado no gráfico, se as linhas estiverem separadas, o eixo dos x pode variar entre 5 e 17.5, no primeiro gráfico, e entre 10 e 40, nos dois últimos. E os eixos dos y também são muito diferentes.

No código que se segue, utilizo o `cut` para criar o factor `Group` que no código da pergunta se chama `Factor` e é criado com uma série de `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

datanew2 %>%
  mutate(Group = cut(Var3, breaks = c(-Inf, 5, 11, 16, 20), labels = LETTERS[1:4])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var2, Var1, group = Group)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'gam', formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"))
```

---

### Leitura dos dados

```
google_id <- "1eWNHSuYuKbXakJv9w9hd8rDPSvXPuxUf"
google_file <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", google_id)
datanew2 <- read.csv2(google_file)
```

Comment: @BrenoG. O último `ifelse(Var3 < 20, "D")` não está correto, não tem o valor para a alternativa `no`, quando `Var3 >= 20`. Talvez removendo-o, ficando só com `ifelse(Var3 < 16, "C", "D")`. Quanto ao gráfico, com todos os níveis do fator, esse sim, está correto. É até bastante simples.